# How can I get a specifc selection in select vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How are you?
I'm studying Vue and I'm stuck on the current task not knowing where to go.
I have a select that when I click I need to show on screen only what corresponds to that selection. For example, when placing the "to do" option in the select, only the tasks with a `concluded=false` should appear on the screen. I've only gotten this far and I need help to continue. Can you help me? Thanks

This is my App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Lista de Tarefas</h1>
    <List :data="list" @remove="handleRemove"/>
    <Form @add="addNewTask" @onChange="handleN"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import List from "./components/List.vue";
import Form from "./components/Form.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    List,
    Form,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      list: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTask(newTask) {
      this.list.push(newTask);
    },
    handleRemove(item) {
      const index = this.list.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id)
      this.list[index].excluded = true
    },
    handleN(item) {
      const index = this.list.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id)
      this.list[index].concluded = true
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

This is my List.vue

```js
<template>
  <ul>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange($event)">
      <option disabled value="">Escolha a visualização</option>
      <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.text">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>

    <li v-for="item in itens" :key="item.id">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="item.concluded" />
      <label for="checkbox"> {{ item.description }} </label>
      <button @click="() => $emit('remove', item)">Excluir</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      options: [
        { text: "Todos", value: "1" },
        { text: "A fazer", value: "2" },
        { text: "Concluído", value: "3" },
        { text: "Deletado", value: "4" },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    itens() {
      return this.data.filter((item) => item.excluded === false);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      return this.data.filter((item) => item.concluded === false);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is my Form.vue

```js
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleNewTask">
    <input type="text" v-model="newTask" placeholder="Insira a tarefa"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Adicionar"/>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import Task from '../types/Task.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newTask: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
      handleNewTask() {
          this.$emit('add', new Task(this.newTask))
          this.newTask = ''
      }
  },
};
</script>
```

And this is my Task.js

```js
export default class {
    constructor(description) {
        this.description = description,
        this.id = Math.random(),
        this.concluded = false,
        this.excluded = false
    }
}
```

I watch some tutorials, read the documentation and some StackOverflow questions but I really can't get out of here
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you have structured your app, our only concern should be with the `List.vue` file.

Your goal is to filter the results based on the selection (`selected` property). However, your issue is that you are not even using that anywhere.

I know you are hard coding the filter on the `onChange` method but that is, first of all wrong because you aren't really changing anything (you are returning an array), and secondly it's inefficient.

A better way to do it is to update the computed `itens` function like so:

```
itens() {
  return this.data.filter((item) => {
    if (this.selected === '1'){
      return item.concluded === false
    } else if (this.selected === '2'){
      // filter another way
    } else if (... // so on and so forth
  });
},
```

Also, I would filter out the `excluded` items before sending them to the component. If you aren't going to use it, don't send it.

Remove the `onChange` event on the `<select>` and the associated method since they are now unused.